# CSS selector for direct table `th` element without child table's `th` element - is possible

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How to select the `th` element of table without selecting it's child `th`? is it possible? is there any selector like so?

here is the demo:

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

thead:first-of-type th {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>one</th>
          <th>tow</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>A</th>
          <th>B</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>x</th>
                  <th>y</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

When i add the gray background it added with tables child elements of the too. is there any direct selector to only select the parent level `th` element?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one class to the main table. Try this code

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.parent-table>thead:first-of-type th {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<table class="parent-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>one</th>
          <th>tow</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>A</th>
          <th>B</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>x</th>
                  <th>y</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: agree. I know this solution already. trying to get without class selector. since the table loads from backend as dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

table > thead:first-of-type > tr > th {
  background-color: gray;
}

table > tbody > tr td table > thead:first-of-type > tr > th{
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>one</th>
          <th>tow</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>A</th>
          <th>B</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>x</th>
                  <th>y</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```